# How to use barchart-udt in Android?

Tags: java, android

I try to download UDT from Maven Repo (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.barchart.udt%7Cbarchart-udt-core%7C2.3.0%7Cjar)

I only download the core-2.3.0.jar file and add it to android studio. When I try to use it, it say "Unsupported platform".

There is also 
barchart-udt-core-2.3.0-arm-Linux-gpp-jni.nar
barchart-udt-core-2.3.0-arm-Linux-gpp-jni.nar.asc

I am not sure what is .nar and .asc file are and Is that suppose to be added to android studio as well ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add this in your build.gradle and sync

```
compile group: 'com.barchart.udt', name: 'barchart-udt-bundle', version: '2.3.0'
```